# What are the hidden achievements in Words With Friends for iOS?

Tags: ios, words-with-friends

There are 2 'Hidden' achievements for Words With Friends for iOS. How do you unlock them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One is 150+ word and one is you need to play 30 games at a time, it's called "Maxed out"

Answer (score 0):

One of them requires you to play a word worth 150+ points. Not sure of the other one yet